# How can I add a scrollbar for side panel when the body overflow is set to hidden?

Tags: html, css, overflow

Here's the JSFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/stgeqjoL/

```
html,
body,
#container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

I have a side panel that will have many divs that will do something when selected.

The body is currently set to hide the overflow, which is making the side panel also hide the overflow, but I want it to scroll.

What do I need to change?

Comment: Why not add `#container {overflow-y: auto}` ?

Comment: Because the container is a map and the overflow can't be on. Only the bottom side panel should be scrollable.

Comment: Well the same idea applies, just find the selector for the side panel and add `overflow-y: auto` there

Comment: For whatever reason it doesn't work.

Comment: You can see that here:
https://jsfiddle.net/stgeqjoL/1/

Comment: Just saw your fiddle. You need to set a height for the sidebar since you're using `position:absolute` See this https://jsfiddle.net/a4nvfmv5/

Comment: Ahh, thanks! You the man!

Comment: No problem, glad it's sorted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a `height` value to the `#sidebar`, along with `overflow: scroll`.

Try:

```
#sidebar {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85);
    width: 350px;
    overflow: scroll;
    height: 100vh;
}
```